# How can you get the 3D space coordinates of the 4 corners of an ImageTarget in Vuforia Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am able to detect images in Vuforia images and overlay 3d objects on them. But I want to draw borders around the ImageTarget.

The problem is that I can only get the center of it such as,

```
productTarget.transform.position
```

How can I get the corners of the image ? It is simply a 2D image but Vuforia doesn't have anything to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect coordinates of the corners, but you can manually calculate it.

[This](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/image-target-width-and-height) will help you to get the height and width of the image

for example: coordinates of upper left corner will be `center - (width/2) - (height/2)`

Comment: getSize() does not return pixels. It returns the size of this target in scene units. I don't know how to use the scene units to apply you calculation

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you just make flat border which you want, and then just resize it on tracking image, because its scale is always the same and vuforia only moves the camera.

[image: target] image
[image: border] border

after tracking just child border to image
[image: parenting] after parenting

Comment: You mean apply a material ?

Comment: no, just make another object like your 3d model, but border

Comment: The problem is that I can't set the size to the same as I don't know the size of the target being tracked

Comment: you can get imageTarget.transform.localScale (as in question you have transform of your target), then make your border child of your target and set the same scale

Comment: I had something like this: "quad.transform.parent.localScale = transform.localScale" but the quad showed up much larger than the actual real-life target. I am using positional tracker in Vuforia and I had to provide the dimensions for each marker online in meters because of this.

Comment: first, unparent your border, then track image, then set border the same scale as marker, then parent your border and set localposition to 0,0,0

Comment: The problem is that I not setting the image targets from the UI, but from code.. :|

Comment: its not problem. get reference of your border gameobject, when image target is lost call
    border.transform.SetParent(anygameobjectTransform);
    border.SetActive(false);

On detection image you can call
    border.transform.SetParent(imageTarget.transform);
    border.SetActive(true);

Comment: What I meant is that I can't draw the borders in code. The image targets are loaded programatically so they are not under the Scene editor, if that makes sense